# SVM optimizing in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, svm

I am brand new to R, SVMs and parallel processing :S

I have the following code to optimise the SVM:

```
library(e1071)    
# Perform a grid search of SVM predictions of the training data set using a range of gamma and cost values
    tuneResult <- tune(svm, ActualDepth ~ . , data=trainset, ranges=list(gamma=seq(0.6,0.8,0.1),cost=seq(180,190,5)))
    print(tuneResult)    # Print the results of the grid search to screen
    plot(tuneResult)     # Plot the results of the grid search to a contour plot
```

Now I would like to parallelise this code to use the whole of my cpu. I've tried several connotations of the following code, but it doesn't seem right and I'm not sure if the output is the best result or simply the last result. I'm hoping it's the the last result because if it's the best result then it's not very good! Please can you help me correct the following code so that, either I get the optimal gamma and cost out, or I can get something like the output plot of the tune function above

```
# Use all CPU
library(foreach)
library(doSNOW)

G = seq(0.6,0.8,0.01)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores()-1)
registerDoSNOW(cl)

parResult <- foreach(i = 1:length(G), combine = "combine") %dopar% {
    library(e1071)
    svm(ActualDepth ~ ., data = trainset, gamma = G[i], cost = 1)
}
stopCluster(cl)
parPred <- predict(parResult[[1]],testset[,-1])
plot(testset[,1],parPred)
abline(0,1,col="red")
abline(-8,1,col="green")
abline(8,1,col="green")
```

I've conducted a websearch on this problem and whilst I have found some resources, they weren't anything I could use directly and I don't have enough R to modify them, or often to understand what they are doing. I would really appreciate some help with this problem, I've been working on it non-stop for 2 days now.

Many thanks

Comment: 5 years past but the problem is still not developed by the e1071 package.